# Incorrect black level and white level shift in chrome browser

Tags: google-chrome, video, graphics-card

My video shows perfect black `(0,0,0)` and white `(255,255,255)` levels in `mpc-be player`. When I open the same file in `Chrome browser` they are shift a bit to `(1,0,1)` and `(255,254,255)`. What might be the problem?

```
79.0.3945.130 (Official Build) (64-bit) (cohort: Stable)
Windows 10 OS Version 1909 (Build 18363.657)
nVidia GTX 1060
```

[Chrome video options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/okeJY.png)

Comment: I'm curious what you're doing with that video that makes 0.2% color difference significant. I suppose it would be hard to notice with naked eye on a professionally calibrated display, not to mention typical crappy laptop screens.

Comment: It could be a matter of codec decoding issue. If you make a raw video that has no compression, it should be the same everywhere. Does it happen then too?

Comment: I converted this file to `rawvideo.yuv`. Neither Chrome nor mpc plays it. Not shure how can I test that. `Opera browser` does the same as `Chrome` `(1,0,1)` and `(255,254,255)`.

Comment: Opera and Chrome both use Chromium framework, so that's a bad test. Test it in FireFox or Safari if you want a different browser, or test it in a different media player

Comment: I tried this in `Tor browser` (as I suppose it is Firefox), it shows perfect `(0,0,0)` and `(255,255,255)`. `Youtube` videos play as `(1,0,1)` and `(255,255,255)` in `Chrome`.

Answer (score 0):

This is insane bug in Chrome gpu YCbCr shader decoder that I reported eons ago. It is thus present in all codecs, VP9, AVC. You can fix it by doing --disable-gpu or for limited YCbCr using new SW overlays from Nvidia Turing. Full YCbCr is broken even with SW overlays.

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1068690#c79